# parsing the date to calculate days until cert expiry from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I would like to get the days until a cert expires. Extracting the dates is easy with openssl

```
> cat cert | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
notAfter=Jun  8 17:07:09 2021 GMT
```

Unfortunately parsing the date `Jun  8 17:07:09 2021 GMT` and finding the days until today is not so straight forward. The goal would be to have

```
> cat cert | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | ...some commands...
15
```

Meaning 15 days until the cert expires.

I am aware of the openssl `-checkend` option, but that is just a boolean and I want the number of days.

Comment: Very useful, Cyrus. Very useful. Guess what I did before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use this one liner shell script:

```
expiryDays=$(( ($(date -d "$(openssl x509 -in cert -enddate -noout | cut -d= -f2)" '+%s') - $(date '+%s')) / 86400 ))
```

Here is the breakup:

- `openssl ...` command to print expiry date in `notAfter=...` format
- `cut -d= -f2` to get text after `=`
- `date -d '+%s'`: to get EPOCH seconds value for expiry date
- `date '+%s'`: to get EPOCH seconds value for today's date
- `(epochExpiry - epochToday) / 86400`: to get difference of 2 EPOCH date-time stamps in number of days

Comment: This looks almost perfect. Unfortunately `date -d "Jun  8 17:07:09 2021 GMT" +%s` seems to only work on linux. On macOS -d sets the kernel's value for daylight saving time.

Comment: Yes of course but since you used `linux` tag in question this solution should work there. btw I also use mac but have gnu utilities installed using `home brew` to make it work

Comment: Fair point. For that I should have asked for a POSIX solution.

Answer (score 1):

A quickie perl script using the [`Date::Parse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse) module (Install through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Parse;
use feature qw/say/;

my $certdate = str2time($ARGV[0]);
my $now = time;
my $expiresecs = $certdate - $now;
say int(($expiresecs / (60 * 60 * 24)));
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./showdays "Jun  8 17:07:09 2021 GMT"
67
```