# Trying to count remaining days from ssl cert from now

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I am trying to a write a bash script which would take out put of openssl -enddate command and compare it with dateutil.ddiff now and wanted to know how many days are remaining.

```
SSLDATE=`openssl x509 -noout -in wild.crt -enddate | sed -e 's/notAfter=//g' | awk '{print $4"-""03""-"$2}'`
```

Now I have installed dateutils package which provides me this facility. However I am not getting how do I calculate the with $SSLDATE - $now?

Plus is there a way since openssl -enddate gives Month in alphabet format while dateutils accepts in numeric format

Any idea how to achieve it?
For example

```
dateutils.ddiff 2021-04-12 2022-04-15 -f '%dd'
**368d**
```

Or is there any other alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternate solution not requiring `dateutils`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921470/13982210

---

I am not familiar with `openssl` nor `dateutils`. However, the solution I can offer (which may not be the best or most efficient) is:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# line broken with \ for readability
ssldate=$(openssl x509 -noout -in example.crt -enddate \
    | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')
    # alternatively
  # | cut -d = -f 2

# use the variable `$ssldate` in your `dateutils` command
dateutils.ddiff today "$(date --date="$ssldate" '+%F')" -f '%dd'
```

#### Things to note

- UPPERCASE variables are not preferred in scripting to avoid clashing with system/shell env variables. [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/13982210)
- the backtick syntax ``` `` ``` is deprecated in favour of `$()` which supports nesting

#### Explanations

Sorry I do not have a list of references for further reading on any of the concepts. Hopefully, man pages and/or search engines can fill in.

- `$(command)` command substitution. newer syntax of ``` `` ``` to convert output of command within to string that can be used as argument in another command or stored in a variable
- `openssl ... | awk ...` the `|` pipe operator takes the standard output from the LHS and passes it as the standard input to the RHS
- `awk` works on the data received via piped standard input in the absence of a filename argument

  - usually works on **fields**. think of text as a table of rows and columns.
  - `-F '='` sets the **field separator** as `=` - i.e. the character that splits each line into fields (space by default)
  - `'{print $2}'` prints the **second** field
- alt: `cut` same principle. `-d` sets the **delimiter** that does the field splitting. `-f` the field number
- `date [-d | --date=]<DATESTRING> '+%F'` (GNU date) - format  as `%F` full date (`YYYY-MM-DD`)

Comment: Yep - That works fine. However only glitch I see is openssl actual enddate show in below format and %m or Month I entered manually just for testing purpose wondering how do I convert the current month at run time.
```
openssl x509 -noout -in wild.crt -enddate | sed -e 's/notAfter=//g'
Mar 14 16:43:04 2022 GMT

```

Comment: updated the answer to suit your case @BlasonR

Comment: Great Thanks man!!

Comment: let me know if it works as expected

Comment: Unfortunately nope - it did not. This command gives me the current date
openssl x509 -noout -in wild.crt -enddate | awk -F '= '{print $2}' | date '+%Y-%m-%d'

2021-04-15

Comment: updated and checked. should work as expected @BlasonR

Comment: Yep - Looks like its working. Though I am testing it carefully :)

Comment: Thanks - Its working as expected. Keen to know what exactly done here. I am not pro in bash scripting 
awk -F '=' '{print $2}')